# CORS Error while fetching Data from local host

Tags: node.js, next.js, cors

I am running both next js and nodejs from local machine

Next js code to post the data

```js
const url = `http://localhost:8000'/events`;
        const res=await fetch(url,{
        method:'POST',
          headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
          },
          body:JSON.stringify({name:"Jon"})
        })
        console.log(res);
       const response=await res.json();
       console.log(response);
```

From this page i am trying to post the data
`http://localhost:3000/events/add`

In nodejs application i have already use

```
app.use(cors({
    origin:'*'
}))
```

From React application i am able to make the request and its working perfectly fine  but not for next js. what should i do?

I am trying to resolve the cors issue for nextjs

Comment: Please show where (in your server code) your routes are defined compared to `app.use(cors(...))`. Before or after?

Comment: Also, edit your question and add the CORS error's message.

Answer (score 2):

1. Change URL from `http://localhost:8000'/events` to `http://localhost:8000/events`

Is your node server on port 8000 or 3000?

If your node server is on port 3000 then you need to change the value of 'const url' to: `http://localhost:3000/events`

Do you use `/events` or `/events/add` to POST a new event? Then change your url to:

- `http://localhost:3000/events` or
- `http://localhost:3000/events/add`